# Most efficient way to add "show results within X miles of zip code" filter to website

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to add a "show results within X miles of zip code" filter to my django site. I am using a file with all US zip codes in the format `ZIP,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE\n` (https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666), I plan on having a function get the user entered zip code, get the lat and long of that zip code from this file and then run some calculations to find all zip codes within a certain distance. My question is about the most efficient way to do this. Is saving this long file as a .txt, storing it on a server and having my website access this file and run these commands on the fly when a user uses the filter the best way of doing this? Will this cause a long load time?

Comment: probably store and read the data in a database might be the fastest https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/optimization/

Comment: If you really need efficiency, you probably want a microservice that all of your front-end servers talk to for lookups. That microservice can keep the whole text file in memory—or, better, it can transform it into something that can be searched in logarithmic rather than linear time and keep _that_ in memory. If you need to scale up even further, you'll want to turn it into a dedicated server that you can break down into regions (with X mlles of overlap) and shard.

Comment: thanks @abarnert but thats leagues above my current capabilities

Comment: OK, then you don't really need the "most efficient way". (Or, if you _do_, you're probably out of luck.) Can you give us some idea of what kind of scale and latency you're looking for? Is this a single server that's going to handle a few dozen connections per second and only needs to respond within a few seconds?

Comment: yes, I'm attempting to get a working version of a job site going to gain traction so probably very little users at first. I've already handled everything but this zip code filter I would like to add. Do you think I should create a `ZipCode` model with the fields `zip_code`, `latitude` and `longitude` then fill this database using the file at https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666) and then make queries from there?

Comment: @abamert not sure if you saw the above comment without including your @